# warning: [deprecation]in thread

Tags: java, hilos

### problemas con hilos

como podria resolver este tipo de problemas el programa corre bien pero quisiera saber como arreglar esas advertencias

========================================================================

```
   import java.awt.geom.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class UsoThreads {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JFrame marco=new MarcoRebote();
            marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            marco.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    class PelotaHilos implements  Runnable{
        public PelotaHilos(Pelota unaPelota,Component unComponent){
            pelota=unaPelota;
            componente=unComponent;
        }
         @Override
        public void run(){
            for (int i=1; i<=3000; i++){
                    pelota.mueve_pelota(componente.getBounds());
                    componente.paint(componente.getGraphics());
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(4);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
        private Pelota pelota;
        private Component componente;

    }
    //Movimiento de la pelota-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class Pelota{
        // Mueve la pelota invirtiendo posicion si choca con limites
        public void mueve_pelota(Rectangle2D limites){
            x+=dx;
            y+=dy;
            if(x<limites.getMinX()){
                x=limites.getMinX();
                dx=-dx;
            }
            if(x + TAMX>=limites.getMaxX()){    
                x=limites.getMaxX() - TAMX;
                dx=-dx;
            }
            if(y<limites.getMinY()){    
                y=limites.getMinY();
                dy=-dy;
            }
            if(y + TAMY>=limites.getMaxY()){    
                y=limites.getMaxY()-TAMY;
                dy=-dy;
            }
        }
        //Forma de la pelota en su posicion inicial
        public Ellipse2D getShape(){
            return new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,TAMX,TAMY);
        }   
        private static final int TAMX=15;
        private static final int TAMY=15;
        private double x=0;
        private double y=0;
        private double dx=1;
        private double dy=1;
    }
    // Lamina que dibuja las pelotas----------------------------------------------------------------------
    class LaminaPelota extends JPanel{
        //Anadimos pelota a la lamina   
        public void add(Pelota b){
            pelotas.add(b);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
            for(Pelota b: pelotas){ 
                g2.fill(b.getShape());
            }       
        }
        private ArrayList<Pelota> pelotas=new ArrayList<Pelota>();
    }
    //Marco con lamina y botones------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class MarcoRebote extends JFrame{
        private Thread t;   
        public MarcoRebote(){
            setBounds(600,300,400,350);
            setTitle ("Rebotes");
            lamina=new LaminaPelota();
            add(lamina, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            JPanel laminaBotones=new JPanel();
            ponerBoton(laminaBotones, "Dale!", new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento){
                    comienza_el_juego();
                }
            });
            ponerBoton(laminaBotones,"suspender",new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento){
                    t.suspend();
                }
            });
            ponerBoton(laminaBotones,"reanudar",new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento){
                    t.resume();
                }
            });
            ponerBoton(laminaBotones, "Salir", new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            add(laminaBotones, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
        //Ponemos botones
        public void ponerBoton(Container c, String titulo, ActionListener oyente){
            JButton boton=new JButton(titulo);
            c.add(boton);
            boton.addActionListener(oyente);
        }
        //Anade pelota y la bota 1000 veces
        public void comienza_el_juego (){
            Pelota pelota=new Pelota();
            lamina.add(pelota);
            Runnable r=new PelotaHilos(pelota,lamina);
            //Thread t=new Thread(r);
            t=new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
        private LaminaPelota lamina;
    }
```

---

```
javac UsoThreads.java -Xlint:deprecation && java UsoThreads && rm *.class
UsoThreads.java:101: warning: [deprecation] suspend() in Thread has been deprecated
                t.suspend();
                 ^
UsoThreads.java:106: warning: [deprecation] resume() in Thread has been deprecated
                t.resume();
                 ^
2 warnings
```

Comment: Mira las recomendaciones que te dan para este método (con código) en los [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). Vete a la sección `Why are Thread.suspend and Thread.resume deprecated?` y `What should I use instead of Thread.suspend and Thread.resume?`

Comment: muchas gracias ahora lo veo

Answer (score 0):

El método **resume** de la clase **Thread** está marcado como deprecated, es decir que este metodo es **desfasado o anticuado**, que solo esta presente por compatibilidad con versiones antiguas de la máquina virtual y que por lo tanto es recomendable dejar de usarlo.

[Java SE Documentation - Deprecated APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html)

Comment: muchas gracias por responder